# ArrayList into comma separated string

Tags: java

I have an arrayList that contains

List aList = new ArrayList<>()

```
      aList{
         String name,
         String id
      }
```

I have a map that contains key and value as Strings
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

From the arrayList- Alist I want to combine Name-Id  as one field containing comma separated strings and then add it to a map
Ex:

```
       name-id = John-1, Jack-2 (And no comma at the end)
```

In the Map I want to add something like this

```
       map.put("Name-id", name-id.toString());
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. What is `AList`? Is it some class? An array? Do you mean you have `List<AList>`? Could you show us some code for better understanding? And what you've tried so far as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you need to override method `toString` in `AList` class and then convert `List<AList>` to map using `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.mapping`:

```java
class AList {
    String name, id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.join("-", name, id);
    }
}

List<AList> list = buildList(); // build a list of AList objects

Map<String, List<String>> mapEx = list
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        x -> "Name-id",
        Collectors.mapping(AList::toString, Collectors.toList())
    ));
// get comma-separated string
Map<String, String> mapEx2 = list
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        x -> "Name-id",
        Collectors.mapping(AList::toString, Collectors.joining(", "))
    ));
```

Comment: I am already adding few other fields to map. So instead of creating a new map how I can add it to existing map

Comment: What do you mean, you're adding some fields to map??  Please show some code and provide better explanation what you're trying to do.